# getting an error when using SOAP v2

Tags: magento

I am trying to use SOAP v2 to work in customer details. I added below code.

```
$client = new SoapClient('http://localhost/abc/api/v2_soap/?wsdl');
```

And I got the following warning and fatal error

> Warning: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Warning: SoapClient::SoapClient(http://localhost/abc/api/v2_soap/?wsdl): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! in C:\xampp\htdocs\abc\test.php on line 64' in C:\xampp\htdocs\abc\app\code\core\Mage\Core\functions.php:245 Stack trace: #0 [internal function]: mageCoreErrorHandler(2, 'SoapClient::Soa...', 'C:\xampp\htdocs...', 64, Array) #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\abc\test.php(64): SoapClient->SoapClient('http://localhos...') #2 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\abc\app\code\core\Mage\Core\functions.php on line 245
>
> Fatal error: SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'http://localhost/abc/api/v2_soap/?wsdl' : failed to load external entity "http://localhost/abc/api/v2_soap/?wsdl"

Comment: @KNM Try with  http://127.0.0.1/abc/api/V2_soap?wsdl=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `http://localhost/abc/api/V2_soap?wsdl=1`

if still you are facing problem, add your test.php code here.